# Centos :: Can't delete file with "rm" under "/", operation is not permitted

Tags: centos, malware, rm

I have a CentOS server.It has been hasked.There are some malicious file under "/", like "/11db32e5", the AV scanner say it is a "HackTool/Linux.CoinMiner.n". But i cannot delete the file with "rm -rf". I am the root, uid is 0.

I have tried:

1. lsattr, there is no "i" or "a".
2. lsof /11db32e5, there is no process opening it.
3. The owner and group of the file are both "root".
4. I can run "cat /dev/null > /11db32e5", and the size of the file is 0. But i can not delete it.
5. I make a new dir under "/" with named "/test", and make a file under "/test" with named "test2". Then I can delete "test2", but i can not delete "/test" which is under "/".
6. So i think i can not delete anything under "/", but i can change the content of them.
7. The privilege of "/" mount is "rw".
8. I use "strace" to find the different of "rm -rf" of the malicious file and the regular file which i can delete.

The difference are:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjmRw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ9yd.png)

Comment: did you try sync to ensure file ID/state is updated ... try lsof to check if file is still opened by a process too

Comment: I have tried lsof, there is no process opening it. I didn't try sync, because it is a big server, i am cautious.